# How to disable `clean-aindent-mode` in spacemacs configuration

Tags: spacemacs, indentation

I noticed that `clean-aindent-mode` is messing up the indentation as I am writing python files. Hence, I wanted to disable this mode, at least when using python mode.

I can manually disable this mode, but I was wondering what the correct code was to disable `clean-aindent-mode` in my spacemacs configuration file? I imagine it is something simple, but I don't really know emacs lisp.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to have been added to a recent Spacemacs dev branch. Press `SPC-f-e-d` to open your config file, find the `*/init` section as shown below, and add in the one liner to disable.

```lisp
(defun dotspacemacs/init ()
  "Initialization:
This function is called at the very beginning of Spacemacs startup,
before layer configuration.
It should only modify the values of Spacemacs settings."
...
   ;; If non nil activate `clean-aindent-mode' which tries to correct
   ;; virtual indentation of simple modes. This can interfer with mode specific
   ;; indent handling like has been reported for `go-mode'.
   ;; If it does deactivate it here.
   ;; (default t)
   dotspacemacs-use-clean-aindent-mode nil

...
)
```

Comment: thanks for the response to the question. I found that I needed to do `(setq dotspacemacs-use-clean-aindent-mode nil)` to get this to work. Does that make sense to you? I am not an elisp programmers, so I don't really know the syntax that well.

Comment: That is equivalent, though Spacemacs suggests putting all `dotspacemacs-*` variables inside that `dotspacemacs/init` block.

Comment: Okay cool. Yes, thanks for clarifying. Someday I will sit down and work through all of the elisp tutorials :).